# Search - multiple search terms

Tags: search, interface

I'm working on a mobile app that allows users to search for events around the UK. The issue I'm having is that the system allows a user to search for events in multiple locations. On the search page, the user can click on the locations text field, which then opens a locations drawer. The user can then search for locations, with the aid of autocomplete, and add as many as they like.

Once they have selected the locations, they return to the main page to run the search.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm worried that this way of handling multiple locations isn't very clear and the users might be confused when they see the 4th screen.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I hope I don't get downvote for posting this, but I thought you can simplify the entire design by integrating the search locations within the search bar. The interface would look something like this:
[image: sample interface showing keywords within a search bar]

Although there's one caveat assuming that users will search for less than 5 locations at any time. Having more would make the page cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffr8I7.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

You've point with your concern. I can suggest a way to work around while first 3 screen is appropriate as how they should be as I can think of.

The thing is I wish to be the selected locations to be bolder but it was not applicable within the editor here.

**An Extra Point:** Not related with a question's itself but I also suggest to use the 'Search Events' button as the same spaced distance with the above heading 'Event Finder's range with 'Locations' and it's search bar.

Note: Hope it helps, please ask for any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a +2 or a list of places are both appropriate..If you tap on that bar and the add or remove screen appears again then using a +number seems like less clutter. Specially if there are many locations and it's not a text field they can manually edit the text.

Answer (score 0):

It could be enough to have the +2 indicator there. Another option would be to have them listed as chips, as you have a lot of estate. But I have a question. Is the approach of selecting multiple locations the best for what you are building? 
You did not state the type of events or the location types ( they seem like venues Park etc. ) so I am thinking why would people search by venue instead of area or a custom range from one point.